# How can I see the flag ID of a flag I raised?

Tags: support, flags

I raised a comment flag. How can I see its flag ID?

I don't see it on https://*.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @Xnero to point a mod to a flag.

Comment: Can’t you just link them to the comment you flagged?

Comment: @Xnero comment was removed

Comment: You can link the relevant post and they can look through the deleted comments, or they can just look through the flags on your profile.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino true but I like the simplicity and univocity of a flag ID.

Comment: +1 because I want to know too, but I am now realizing... even on the site I moderate, I can't seem to find how to get the ID of a flag. Surely there has to be some internal ID, but I don't even know if it's accessible from the UI... Anyway, hoping for an answer!

Comment: Displaying a flag Id would not be of any use. There's no UI for looking up flags by Id.

Comment: @animuson thanks you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flag IDs aren't really used anywhere, and I wouldn't know what to do with one. The easiest way to reference a flag is to reference the post it (or the comment you flagged) is on. If you feel like saving us a click, link directly to one of these:

- List of flags & comment flags on the post: `/admin/posts/[post-id]/show-flags`
- Timeline (includes flags & comment flags for mods): `/posts/[post-id]/timeline`